# Android how to use the same fragment in viewpager2 for different tabs in tablayout

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I have a tabLayout that has four tabs (tab0, tab1, tab2, tab3). I need to have tab0 and tab1 use the same fragment and layout but with different data as parameters.

How to implement this concept in Viewpager2 and how to pass the parameters to the fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solutions is using a baseFragment and other fragments inheriting it to avoid repetition of code and layout.